# this object not getting passed to object method

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code snippet which is as following:

```js
var obj = {
  message: "Hello",
  innerMessage: !(function() {
    console.log(this.message);
  })()
};

console.log(obj.innerMessage);
```

It outputs: `undefined true`

The function which gets executed for evaluating `innerMessage` property prints the `message` property of the object on which the method is called. The value of that property is `Hello`. However what gets printed is `undefined`. It looks like the object is not getting passed to the method. Why is it happening?

Comment: Because the function isn't invoked in the context of `obj` but rather it's an IIFE with its context set to the global scope (`window`)

Comment: Notice that when defining an object literal, you can't refer the object under creation before the object is fully defined.

Comment: In this case when would IIFE gets executed?

Comment: It is IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), i.e. it is invoked as soon as it is met during the object definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It outputs: undefined true

`undefined` is due to `console.log` statement in IIFE

```
(function() {
        console.log(this.message);
    })() //prints undefined and returns `undefined`
```

And `true` is because `innerMessage` is a `boolean` as you negated `!undefined` ==> `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = {
      message: "Hello",
      innerMessage: !(function() {
      })()
    };
    obj.innerMessage = function(){
     alert(this.message);
    }

obj.innerMessage();
```

If you want to get the message, You can use this.message after you created object you need to make function decleration.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: yes,worked fine in .goto chrome press f12, then try.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, that was saved object already I tried from questioner code..

Comment: OK. Althought now your example doesn't make any sense. That way you could define `innerMessage` within the object literal as well. It is not clear what OP actually wants to do, hence it's not useful to speculate with alternative codes, right?